# Rails/Gsub - Conditional prefix to anchor href programmatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gsub

I want to track clickthroughs of links by sending users to my api and then redirecting. As a result, when they generate a url, I want to run some sort of code that will replace the entire `href` of an `anchor` to some api call plus their destination.

Example of regular `anchor` :

`<a href="http://localhost:3000/dulce.html#"></a>`

Since that url ends in `dulce.html#`, then I want to replace it to just be #. (`<a href="#"></a>`) But, if it doesn't end in `dulce.html#`, then I want to append something to the beginning so it's something like this:

`<a href="http://api.tracking.com/destination=http://localhost:3000/world.html"></a>`

I have very little experience with gsub and can't seem to figure out the syntax to make this conditional switch happen.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to use gsub for this. You could do this:

```
link = '<a href="http://localhost:3000/dulce.html#"></a>'
# Get the href
href = /\<a\shref\=\"(.+)\"\>\<\/a\>/.match(link)[1]

# If you want to know if the href ends with a '#'
if href.last(1) == '#'
  # Do something here
  new_link = '<a href="#"></a>'
end

# If you want to know if it ends in 'dulce.html#'
if href.last(11) == 'dulce.html#'
  # Do something here
  new_link = "<a href='http://api.tracking.com/destination=#{href}'></a>"
  # Which would result in 
  # <a href="http://api.tracking.com/destination=http://localhost:3000/world.html"></a>
  # If href is http://localhost:3000/world.html
end
```

You can use the excellent http://www.regexpal.com/ to test your regular expressions.

Hope this helps!